# Gestionar invocaciones concurrentes (WCF) C#

Tags: c#, wcf

Estoy desarrollado un cronómetro para practicar un poco `WCF`. En este caso servidor se encarga de hacer un decremento de `x` a `0` y cliente recibe en tiempo real el estado de éste.

El problema que tengo es que si ejecuto varios clientes al mismo tiempo el cronómetro multiplica el decremento en 1 por cada nueva instancia en ejecución.

¿Podríais explicarme la mejor manera de tratar con instancias distintas, tengo que realizar algún control en los clientes que consumen mi servicio para que no colapsen el servidor llamando todos a la misma función al mismo tiempo?

Por cierto no se si lo he planteado bien pero cliente tiene un temporizador que cada segundo llama a una función (de servidor) que hace el descenso del cronómetro, ¿podríais explicarme la manera más optima de hacer la cuenta atrás teniendo en cuenta de no sobrecargar el servidor y que sea capaz de gestionar muchas instancias simultáneamente?

Algún ejemplo sencillo me iría muy bien para aclararme más.

**Clase Service**

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession,
                     ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
    public class Service : IService
    {
        public static int contador = 10;

        public int DecrementoContador()
        {
            if (contador > 0)
            {
                return contador--;
            }
            else if(contador == 0)
            {
                contador = 10;
                return 10;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Interfaz IService**

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int DecrementoContador();
    }
}
```

**Timer en cliente**

```
    private async void tm_contador_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyServices.ServiceClient client = new MyServices.ServiceClient();
        var contador = await client.DecrementoContadorAsync();

        if (contador > 0)
        {
            contador--;
            lb_cronometro.Text = contador.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            tm_contador.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: debes mostrarnos que has hecho hasta ahora, y porque cada cliente no tiene su propio timer?

Comment: En principio cada vez que se ejecuta una instancia nueva de mi cliente este debería tener su propio timer, el problema que tengo es cuando ejecuto más de un cliente simultáneamente y tratan de consumir al mismo tiempo el servicio, por lo que he podido deducir parece que compartan una misma instancia pero no se como gestionar este caso y hay poca información por la red. Saludos.

Comment: Es extraño, ya que `InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession` debería crear una instancia diferente para cada cliente. De todas maneras la variable `contador` probablemente debería ser `private`